# Processing open a virtual serial port

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, virtual, processing

I'm using [processing](http://www.processing.org/) lib and I want create a virtual Serial port with it, and with oter read, have much examples for read Serial ports but I not found how to open a serial port, how I can make this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you cited, http://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial.html:

```
// Example by Tom Igoe

import processing.serial.*;

// The serial port:
Serial myPort;       

// List all the available serial ports:
println(Serial.list());

// Open the port you are using at the rate you want:
myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);

// Send a capital A out the serial port:
myPort.write(65);
```

Comment: I getting 0 ports in Serial.list(), if I print Serial.list().length the out is 0

Comment: Sounds like your library isn't finding any serial ports on your hardware :)  The API can't help you there - it's an OS/configuration issue.

Comment: Google for "linux virtual serial port", if you don't already have a solution.  For example: [How to create a virtual serial/COM port](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-create-a-virtual-serial-com-port-in-linux-797851/), or [Linux virtual Serial Port](http://darebux.blogspot.com/2007/12/linux-virtual-serial-port.html).  I'm not sure of your specific environment or requirements, but that should get you started.

Comment: yes, I'm learning it. I'm searching it a long time today, but thanks for all :).